# Moving on from Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide, qtp, katalon-studio

I work in a small firm whose product is a relatively simple web-based software. For the last several years we have used Selenium IDE and it's record-and-play functionality. It has delivered 98% of what we need. However, now that Selenium IDE will no longer be working several months from now, we must find an alternative. We considered using Selenium WebDriver, but none of us no know programming and we just don't have the time to all learn it quickly enough to maintain our current testing. So, we are looking for something that has at minimum the following features...

- Has record-and-play functionality (as opposed to programming)
- Can support multiple web browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari)
- Can generate reports
- Will continue to be supported for years to come
- Has either a large user community or good company customer service
- Database connect would be nice
- Hopefully, we can import our existing Selenium IDE scripts, rather than rewrite them.
- We are willing to pay if it's good.

There are literally dozens of options for software and I don't have a clear path to selecting one. Some promising software is...
 - Katalon Recorder and Studio. It looks like an excellent replacement for Selenium IDE. But it has small community for help
 - QTP - A colleague previously worked with this and recommends it. It looks like an excellent alternative for webdriver, as it allows record and play. But it is very expensive.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you look at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sideex/?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Having said that, you might ask this on sqa.stackexchange.com. Take a look at Coded UI. It's part of Microsoft's Visual Studio.

Comment: Though the question might get closed but u should have a look at TestComplete in additon to Katalon. I have not used them, well have never used selenium ide too, so not sure it will meet the parameters you laid out...

Comment: You work in a shop that creates a website, and _nobody_ knows how to program?

Answer (score 1):

As per your feature requirement here are a couple of viable *Selenium IDE* [alternatives](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/) :

- [Protractor](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/) :

  Pros :

  ```
  1. Simple installation. Only a couple of commands needed to install Selenium WebDriver and start testing.
  2. Uses JavaScript which is easy to learn with limited programming background.
  ```

  Cons :

  ```
  1. Though flexible but still evolving. Setting up the project and the reporting plugins needs a bit of expertise.
  2. Requires clear understanding of sync/async behavior.
  ```
- [Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/) :

  Pros :

  ```
  1. No experience required for installation.
  2. Unzip the package and ready to go.
  3. No additional plug-ins are required.
  4. The scripting interface allows an user to switch between the keyword-base table and the code editor.
  ```

  Cons :

  ```
  1.Though web automation and mobile automation is achievable API testing module needs more buildup.
  ```
- [Selenium Builder](http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/) :

  [Pros](https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/selenium-builder) :

  ```
  1. Selenium Builder contains a lot of code from Selenium IDE and Webdriver.
  2.  The project is getting forked into a modern and a legacy version.
  ```

  [Cons](https://github.com/SeleniumBuilder/se-builder/) :

  ```
  1. As of version 40, Firefox requires all extensions to be signed and as it contains code from Selenium IDE and Webdriver it is getting rejected from signing.
  2. Getting Selenium Builder into an acceptable state for signing means removing the existing code, which will remove support for Selenium 1.x and support for local playback of Selenium 2.x.
  ```

So it's a mix-bag situation and you can always pick one up and drop the other one at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

QTP I believe has now become UFT (Unified Functional Test) which does have a record option. Unfortunately what you lack in programming, you'll have to make up for in scripting knowledge (VBScript from what I worked with). It's not impossible but would probably take more effort to learn rather than implementing your own free version of Java/Selenium WebDriver. UFT is extremely expensive especially for a small firm which is a per license fee. If I remember right my last job had multiple licenses each $20k a piece.