# CSS selector with in Selenium IDE records are different when copied from browser development tools

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-ide

For some websites Selenium IDE will record a CSS selector in a different way than the one I get when you copy the selector from the developer tools.
Here's an example page :

https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-woman-they-could-not-silence-kate-moore/1138489968?ean=9781728242576

Price selector on Selenium IDE

`id=pdp-cur-price`

Price selector from dev tools

`div.price-current-old-details:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1)`

or

`span#pdp-cur-price.price.current-price.ml-0`

Add to cart button from IDE

`css=.add-to-cart-button`

Add to cart button from dev tools

`form.focus > input:nth-child(5)`

or

`input.add-to-cart-button.btn-addtocart.btn-pdp-addtocart.btn.btn--commerce.mr-xs`

This of course doesn't help when running the selenium script.

What solutions worked for you in getting accurate CSS selectors?

Comment: The one written by a human which is customized is more reliable than this dev tool auto generated or generated by selenium IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact [Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48460681/7429447) and [Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702281/7429447) suggests near perfect [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447), it is always advisable to formulate more canonical [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) tweaking the element attributes, so the desired WebElements are uniquely identified within the DOM Tree.

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Chrome DevTools not find elements not search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63035359/7429447)
- [Why XPath does not highlighted the yellow mark in Chrome84?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073849/7429447)
- [Chrome 84 Inspect element, find results not highlighted in yellow like before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63075040/7429447)

Comment: In the case of this link, the selector seems to be correct, but it's never found by ChromeHeadless https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71282185/page-elements-seen-in-the-browser-dev-tools-are-not-retrieved-by-chromeheadless

Answer (score 1):

The locators you get by IDE are correct while automatically generated locators from the dev tools are far from being so effective.
I advice you to learn how to create correct and effective locators.
There are many tutorials describing that, for example [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+link+to+google+search+results&oq=create+link+to+google+se&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i22i30l3.15269j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)