# Page elements seen in the browser dev tools are not retrieved by ChromeHeadless

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, google-chrome-headless

In this page :

https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/o-o-by-olivia-oliver-turkish-modal-bath-towel-collection/5469128?categoryId=13434

I can see a button with "Add to Cart" text , I can also see it in dev tools.

But when the same page source is retrieved by ChromeHeadless using selenium, and my script searches for it, this text is not present.

I tried with selecting show page source in the browser, the source too did not have the "Add To Cart text"

Further I used a curl to GET page, "Add To Cart" wasn't in the returned page source either.

What am I doing wrong?

is the page hiding the button?

How can I check for its presence, for product availability check?

Comment: Probably the box for price and ordering are fetched separately after page load, since it's not static (it depends on the availability, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, but how to get around this?

Comment: You need to run all the Javascripts on the page I presume.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements you are looking for are inside the shadow DOM. You need to access the shadow root first. Hard to see exactly what is going on in the DOM without some trial and error, but something like this:

```
WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#wmHostPdp"));
SearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.getShadowRoot();
WebElement addToCart = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector(".shipItBtnCont button"));
```

More info on Shadow DOM & Selenium — https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html